# Was Akame ga Kill Zero stopped?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

I am not able to find any manga chapter of Akame ga Kill Zero after chapter 16. Even in the wikia page, all chapters after chapter 17 don't have any description. Did they stop the series?

Answer (score 5):

> Did they stop the series?

No. The [latest volume (#4)](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4757548648?) contains chapters 21-25, and publication is ongoing in *Monthly Big Gangan*.

If the wikia stops at chapter 17, I'm guessing that's because the scanlators, whoever they are, stalled or dropped the series. It is, in general, unwise to count on wikias being up-to-date. They are, after all, written by random schmoes on the internet.